# Filter results to time range in Traceview

Tags: android, debugging, profiling

Is there a possibility to limit displayed profiling results to specified time range in Android SDK Traceview so I can see relative time spend in methods in narrow perriod of time? Is there any other Android .trace file viewer that can do this?

I need this because the overall perfomance of my application (an OpenGL game) is quite fine but there are noticable hiccups in renering loop and I can't find what is causing them.